# How to configure DbContext with Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I am using Entity Framework 6 (not core).

I am trying to connect to an existing SQL Server table using code (not `app.config`).

I have a simple console application with the following class

```
namespace Acme.AutoOrderMatch.Contexts 
{
    public class AcmeContext : DbContext 
    {
        public AcmeContext(string ConnectionString)
            : base(ConnectionString) 
        { }

        public virtual DbSet<OrdPurchase> OrdPurchase { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<OrdLnPurchase> OrdLnPurchase { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)  
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("OnModelCreating");
        }
    }
}
```

From my program I call the class

```
 AcmeContext cc = new AcmeContext("Server=192....;Database=...;uid=...;pwd=...;");

 foreach (var p in cc.OrdPurchase.ToList()) 
 {
     Debug.WriteLine(p.PONo);
 }
```

When I look the debug pane I can see that the connection is **not open** and the table count is 0.

The `OnModelCreating` debugline is printed to the output window

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The connection string is wrong.  Looks like you are using SQL Server.  I would first connect using SQL Server Management Studio with same connection parameter you are using in the connection string.  The SSMS login window uses either a Windows Authentication (the user logon credentials)  or a SQL Authentication (username and password).  You have to be able to connect with SSMS and be able to perform a query of database before your c# code will work.

Comment: I have tried that too but not sure what parameters I need. when I look in sql the connectionstring should be 
Data Source=192.xxx.xx.xx;User ID=sa;Password=********;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False but that does not work

Comment: I am using SQL servern authentication (not windows authentication)

Comment: Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/how-to-build-an-entityconnection-connection-string) on how to build a connectionString. Basically what is wrong with that connection string, is that your are not even telling EF what the provider is (unless you are in .Net Core in which you pass `DbContextOptionsBuilder` when you register it in Startup.cs)

Comment: Can you connect with SSMS?  If not then you need to add the credentials (username password) to the database.  What is the Server/Instance on the SSMS login window.  Use for server in connection string the Server/Instance in the SSMS login window.

Comment: I can connect to the sql server without any problem using SMS and also using another project that runs core. I will look into @Ergis link

Comment: well, this is so confusing. a lot of talk about visual designer, csdl, ssdl and mdl, edmx etc. but no article that describe the whole solution. I guess need to bounty this

Comment: I use dapper instead 